# CRISP-DM - Timing for each of the tasks?

Tags: analytics, business-intelligence

I have what may be a simple question.

So, using CRISP-DM we have 6 tasks which have to be followed.

How to identify the amount of time needed for each of the tasks?

[image: This is CRISP-DM Tasks Table]

**P.S.** As assumption, for Data Collection we need 3 days.

This is the question, how it's looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no general rule.

Every project is **very different**.

For example, one project may already have all its data, and thus need 0 days to get the data.

Usually, there will be some manager preventing access to the data you need, and then it will take at least 6 months and C-level activity to get the data to you. And absolutely no progress will be possible before seeing the data.

So just plan **0-12 months on every step**.

Also, don't forget that it is an **iterative process**, so you will need to restart again, anyway. In my opinion, CRISP-DM is dead. Business people love it because it gives them the impression of "managing" things, but it doesn't work that way in reality, it is just theater you do for the managers.

Comment: I will update my question, have a look. This is one of my exam question which I do not understand.

Comment: Have a look now please.

Comment: That is a totally useless estimate they demand, and there is *no* way to give a meaningful answer. And yet, I doubt that you will get a USB stick of your "new oil" data in a company as quickly as a week. More likely, six months. Because data is the new oil, and you don't give this to others.
Either way, it is totally pointless to ask such a question, because there is no correct or wrong guess on the time.

Comment: I just have this as a past paper question, but I could not answer it, that's why asking for help.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Could you please answer this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33265/what-to-report-in-the-build-model-asses-model-and-evaluate-results-steps-of-cri Thanks.

Comment: No. I do not use CRISP-DM, to me that is just business bllsht bingo. It's dead.